# Search column for 0, copy to new sheet, and delete row - help needed

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I have already, and it works great in removing #N/As from the range. I am now looking to modify it to do the same thing for cells that contain 0.

```
  Sub DeleteErrorRows()
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).EntireRow
        r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
        r.Delete
    End Sub
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It autofilters your column and keeps rows that have the `findMe` value in your source worksheet. You can set it to 0 as I have in the example or to whatever else you want. It copies those rows (except for the header row) to the target sheet and then deletes them from the source sheet.

Note that this also finds the first empty row on the target sheet so that you can run it multiple times without overwriting what you've already moved to the target sheet.

```
Sub CopyThenDeleteRowsWithMatch()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim firstPasteRow As Long
    Dim findMe As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set tgt = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    firstPasteRow = tgt.Range("B" & tgt.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    findMe = "0"

    Set rng = ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & findMe
        With .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            .Copy tgt.Range("A" & firstPasteRow)
            .Delete
        End With
    End With

    ' turn off the filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub DeleteZeroRows()
        Dim r As Range, rTemp As Range, rB As Range
        Set rB = Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        Set r = Nothing
        For Each rTemp In rB
            If Not IsEmpty(rTemp) And rTemp.Value = 0 Then
                If r Is Nothing Then
                    Set r = rTemp
                Else
                    Set r = Union(r, rTemp)
                End If
            End If
        Next rTemp
        Set r = r.EntireRow
        r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
        r.Delete
End Sub
```